# Problem testing a redux saga not calling api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs, redux-saga

I am having issues with the below test, it appears the saga is not actually calling the "api" function, modules is undefined. When the saga is used in the app without testing it works just fine

```
import { call, put } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { addModule } from "../store/modules";
import { getModulesSaga } from "./ModuleSagas";
import * as api from '../api/app';


it('fetches the modules from the server', () => {
    const generator = getModulesSaga();
    expect(generator.next().value).toEqual(call(api.getModules)); // pass
    expect(generator.next().value).toEqual(put(addModule())); // fail TypeError: modules is not iterable
})
```

sagas/ModuleSagas.ts

```
import { call, put } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { addModule } from "../store/modules";
import * as api from "../api/app";

export function* getModulesSaga() {
    const modules = yield call(api.getModules);

    console.log(modules); // console.log undefined
    
    for (const module of modules) {
        yield put(addModule(module));
    }
}
```

// api/app.ts

```
import noAuthClient from './clients/unauthClient';

export const getModules = async () => {
    console.log('[API] getModules');

    return [
        {id: 1, name: 'Module 1'},
    ]

    //return await noAuthClient.get('/api/modules');
}
```

// jest output

```
 FAIL  sagas/module_sagas.test.js
  ● Console

    console.log
      undefined

      at log (sagas/ModuleSagas.ts:8:13)
          at getModulesSaga.next (<anonymous>)

  ● fetches the modules from the server

    TypeError: modules is not iterable

       8 |     console.log(modules);
       9 |     
    > 10 |     for (const module of modules) {
         |                          ^
      11 |         yield put(addModule(module));
      12 |     }
      13 | }

      at modules (sagas/ModuleSagas.ts:10:26)
          at getModulesSaga.next (<anonymous>)
      at Object.next (sagas/module_sagas.test.js:10:
```

Answer (score 0):

A value must be returned by `yield call(api.getModules);` statement, you can provide the returned value by calling `generator.next(value)`.

An working example:

`saga.ts`:

```
import { call, put } from "redux-saga/effects";
import * as api from "./api";

export const addModule = (payload) => ({ type: 'ADD_MODULE', payload })

export function* getModulesSaga() {
  const modules = yield call(api.getModules);
  console.log(modules);
  for (const module of modules) {
    console.log(module)
    yield put(addModule(module));
  }
}
```

`api.ts`:

```
export const getModules = async () => []
```

`saga.test.ts`:

```
import { call, put } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { addModule, getModulesSaga } from "./saga";
import * as api from "./api";

it('fetches the modules from the server', () => {
  const generator = getModulesSaga();
  expect(generator.next().value).toEqual(call(api.getModules));
  expect(generator.next([{ id: 1, name: 'a' }, { id: 1, name: 'b' }]).value).toEqual(put(addModule({ id: 1, name: 'a' })));
  expect(generator.next().value).toEqual(put(addModule({ id: 1, name: 'b' })));
  expect(generator.next().done).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS   redux-saga-examples  packages/redux-saga-examples/src/stackoverflow/74897357/saga.test.ts (6.476 s)
  ✓ fetches the modules from the server (61 ms)

  console.log
    [ { id: 1, name: 'a' }, { id: 1, name: 'b' } ]

      at packages/redux-saga-examples/src/stackoverflow/74897357/saga.ts:8:11

  console.log
    { id: 1, name: 'a' }

      at packages/redux-saga-examples/src/stackoverflow/74897357/saga.ts:10:13

  console.log
    { id: 1, name: 'b' }

      at packages/redux-saga-examples/src/stackoverflow/74897357/saga.ts:10:13

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |   94.12 |      100 |   66.67 |     100 |                   
 api.ts   |   66.67 |      100 |       0 |     100 |                   
 saga.ts  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        7.704 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```